# SQL query to JOIN two tables returning null when not found

Tags: mysql, sql, join, null

```
table: p
p_id/t_id/
1,35
2,35
3,35
4,35
5,35
6,22
7,22
...
```

**for the table p, all the possible value for p_id has been registered**

```
table: mps
p_id/m_id/value
2,1001,0
4,1001,2
7,1005,1
...
```

**for the table: mps, just a few values of p_id has been registered.**

- How can we **join the two tables** with the following statement?
- the *output* has to be: *p_id, m_id and value.*
- the *input*: *m_id (i.e.:1001) and t_id (i.e.: 35).*

It has to display all the p_id combinations and when it does not find data in the table mps, just display null.

```
output example:
p_id, m_id, value
1,1001,null
2,1001,0
3,1001,null
4,1001,2
5,1001,null
```

I have tried with different SQL queries, but I am not getting the output when p_id is not registered on the table mps:

```
SELECT p.p_id, mps.value, mps.m_id 
FROM p LEFT JOIN
     mps
     ON p.p_id = mps.p_id 
WHERE p.t_id = 35 AND mps.m_id=1001
```

Comment: How will you determine the `m_id` when the `P_id` is not registered? For eg., How did you get `1001` for m_id in the first row of your output  `1,1001,null`. Is `1001` fixed for all rows?

Comment: the m_id is introduced in the input. first: query all the rows where m_id=input. second join the two tables. does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you will get `NULL` mps values for any `p_id` which is not in `mps`, you need to [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) the value of `m_id` to make it equal to `1001` for the values of `p_id` not in `mps`:

```
SELECT p.p_id, COALESCE(mps.m_id, 1001) AS m_id, mps.value
FROM p 
LEFT JOIN mps ON p.p_id = mps.p_id AND mps.m_id = 1001
WHERE p.t_id = 35
ORDER BY p.p_id
```

Output:

```
p_id    m_id    value
1       1001    (null)
2       1001    0
3       1001    (null)
4       1001    2
5       1001    (null)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ccbd5/6)

Alternatively (so as not to repeat the `1001` value) you can `CROSS JOIN` to a derived table consisting of an `m_id = 1001` and then `LEFT JOIN` to `mps`:

```
SELECT p.p_id, m.m_id AS m_id, mps.value
FROM p 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1001 AS m_id) m
LEFT JOIN mps ON p.p_id = mps.p_id AND mps.m_id = m.m_id
WHERE p.t_id = 35
ORDER BY p.p_id
```

Output is the same as the previous query. [Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ccbd5/7)

Comment: We have a winner! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to move the filtering `t_id` to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT p.p_id, mps.value, mps.m_id, 
FROM p LEFT JOIN
     mps
     ON mps.p_id = p.p_id and mps.m_id = 1001
WHERE p.t_id = 35
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it returns the same as my query. i a not getting the p_id not registered for that specific m_id

Comment: @P00LR0CK . . . I added the filtering for `m_id`, which you added into your question after I answered.  The filtering on `mps` needs to be in the `ON` clause.  The filtering on `p` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for in `mps.m_id` is data that sometimes doesn't exist, so you have to provide it yourself;

```
SELECT p.p_id
     , 1001 AS m_id
     , mps.value
FROM p
   LEFT JOIN mps ON p.p_id = mps.p_id AND mps.m_id = 1001
WHERE p.p_id = 35;
```